# How do I write this MySQL query in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want to run

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `ASIN`) as results FROM crawl_results WHERE user_id = 1 and website_id = 1
```

and expect to get 136 results

However

```
`select('ASIN')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('website_id', $scanID)->distinct()->count();`
```

returns all rows in the table of 814

and

```
`select('ASIN')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('website_id', $scanID)->groupby('ASIN')->count();`
```

returns 8 results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create model and use the below code where you require it

```
 use App\CrawlResult;

CrawlResult::where('user_id',1)->where('website_id',1)->distinct('ASIN')->count('ASIN');
```

Comment: distinct() does not take any parameters groupBy('ASIN')->count(); should work

Answer (score 1):

You should write query like this:

```
DB::table('crawl_results')
->select(DB::raw('COUNT(DISTINCT(ASIN)) as results')
->where('user_id', 1)
->where('website_id',1)
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to do it with Eloquent?

Comment: @jamie you can see another answer added above ;)

Comment: @jamie let me know if another answer added above works or not